# Carousel('pause') isn't working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Basically, if I try to pause the carousel programatically it won't work on mobile browsers, it works fine on desktop.

so something like:

```
$('.carousel').carousel('pause');
```

won't take any effect on the carousel itself, it keeps cycling through images.

Also tried:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
```

Then combined it with pause as well with no effect whatsoever.

Is there any particular issue with this or a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is the whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel-indicators').scrollLeft(0);
    $('#sme-directory-gallery').carousel('cycle');

    $('.video-mask').click(function () {
        var iframe = $(this).closest('.item').find('iframe');
        var iframe_source = iframe.attr('src');
        iframe_source = iframe_source + "?autoplay=1"
        iframe.attr('src', iframe_source);
        $(this).toggle();
        $('#sme-directory-gallery').carousel();
    });

    $('#sme-directory-gallery').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        $('#sme-directory-gallery').carousel('cycle');

        var iframeID = $(this).find('iframe').attr('id');
        if (iframeID != undefined) {
            callPlayer(iframeID, 'stopVideo');
        }

        $('.video-mask').show();
        $('#sme-directory-gallery').find('iframe').each(function (key, value) {
            var url = $(this).attr('src');
            if (url.indexOf('autoplay') > 0) {
                var new_url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
                $(this).attr('src', new_url);
            }
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            var scrollTo = $('.list-inline-item.active').position().left;
            if ($('.list-inline-item.active').index() > 0) {
                scrollTo = $('.list-inline-item.active').prev('.list-inline-item').position().left;
            }
            var finalOrFirst = 0;
            if (e.direction === 'right') {
                if ($('.list-inline-item.active').is(':last-child')) {
                    finalOrFirst = 99999;
                }
            } else {
                if ($('.list-inline-item.active').is(':first-child')) {
                    finalOrFirst = -99999;
                }
            }

            var currentScroll = $('.carousel-indicators').scrollLeft();
            var scrollResult = currentScroll + scrollTo + finalOrFirst;
            $('.carousel-indicators').animate({scrollLeft: scrollResult}, 500);
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

Edit 2: this is the html, or blade rather:

```
<div class='card-body text-center sme-directory-card-body sme-directory-gallery'>
    <div id='slider'>
        <div id='sme-directory-gallery' class='carousel slide'>
            <div class='carousel-inner'>
                @foreach($directoryInfo->videos as $index => $video)
                    <div class='item carousel-item {{ $index === 0 ? 'active' : '' }}' data-slide-number='{{ $index }}'>
                        <div class='video-mask'></div>
                        <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
                            <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9'>
                                <iframe class='embed-responsive-item player' src='{{ 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . substr($video->url, strrpos($video->url, 'v=') + 2) . '?rel=0' }}' allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

                @foreach($directoryInfo->images as $index => $image)
                    <div class='item carousel-item {{ ($index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos)) === 0 ? 'active' : '' }}' data-slide-number='{{ $index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos) }}'>
                        <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
                            <img src='{{ asset('storage/' . $image->path) }}' class='img-fluid' alt='imagen'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

                <a class='carousel-control-prev' href='#sme-directory-gallery' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                    <div class='rounded-circle'>
                        <span class='carousel-control-prev-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                        <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class='carousel-control-next' href='#sme-directory-gallery' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                    <div class='rounded-circle'>
                        <span class='carousel-control-next-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                        <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <ul class='carousel-indicators list-inline'>
                @foreach($directoryInfo->videos as $index => $video)
                    <li class='list-inline-item my-2 {{ $index === 0 ? 'active' : '' }}'>
                        <a id='carousel-selector-{{ $index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos) }}' class='sme-gallery-anchor' data-slide-to='{{ $index }}' data-target='#sme-directory-gallery'>
                            <img src='{{ 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . substr($video->url, strrpos($video->url, 'v=') + 2) . '/mqdefault.jpg' }}' class='img-fluid'>
                            <div class='text-white sme-gallery-middle-icon'>
                                <span class='fas fa-play'></span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach

                @foreach($directoryInfo->images as $index => $image)
                    <li class='list-inline-item {{ $index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos) === 0 ? 'active' : '' }}'>
                        <a id='carousel-selector-{{ $index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos) }}' data-slide-to='{{ $index + sizeof($directoryInfo->videos) }}' data-target='#sme-directory-gallery'>
                            <img src='{{ asset('storage/' . $image->path) }}' class='img-fluid'>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just built an example site real quick, and I cannot seem to reproduce this issue... What phone are you using? Maybe it's a browser issue.. The following demo should pause on the second slide, does it work for you? https://oze4.github.io/carousel-test/ ... by the way I tested on a Pixel 3 and it works just fine...

Comment: @MattOestreich I posted my whole code, the only difference I see from yours is that I initialize my carousel with 'cycle' because if I don't the thing wont cycle on page load. A little bit of context, I click on a slide that contains a video, the first click/tap does the pause and loads the video on the iframe

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `cycle` for it to start automatically cycling.. You're going to have to post your HTML as well, as it's hard to determine with just that code.

Comment: @MattOestreich done, it's blade, so some stuff is coming from the database